# How to get Servlet Filter (before/after) behavior in Ratpack Handler?

Tags: groovy, ratpack

I have a Servlet Filter which performs operations before and after the filter chain, something like:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain){
    // I do some stuff here...

    chain.doFilter(req, res);

    // ... and then I do some more stuff here.
}
```

I am converting this to a Ratpack application and have figured out how to use Handlers as filters (in general)

```
class MyHandler implements Handler {
    void handle(Context ctx){
        // so some stuff...

        context.next()
    }
}
```

but the call to `next()` is non blocking so the followup operations are performed right away rather than after the other handlers have executed.

How can I get this before and after code behavior in Ratpack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what your "after" logic is doing and whether you're already rendering a response before your "after" logic you could use context.onClose()

```
class MyHandler implements Handler {
    void handle(Context ctx){
        // so some stuff...

        context.onClose(requestOutcome -> {
            // do some more stuff...
        })

        context.next()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed.